# Multi-line Stackviews Programmatically In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I'm working with a horizontal stackView composed of UIView subclasses. Right now, when the width of the stackView exceeds the width of the superview, the subviews truncate.

What I'd want to happen is that the view that exceeds the width of the superview wraps to a new line.

Is this something that can be done programmatically with stackView's capabilities, or does this have to be custom written?

Comment: I think you want a UICollectionView instead...

Comment: @Sweeper Good call, I was thinking that - I'm adding a feature to something already built, and trying to avoid rebuilding the whole thing.